# Variadic Tuple Types: example from the docs

Tags: typescript

TS beginner.
In [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) it says in JS we could have such function:

```
function concat(arr1, arr2) {
  return [...arr1, ...arr2];
}
```

Then it says

> For concat, the only valid thing we could do in **older versions of
> the language** was to try and write some overloads.

And then proceeds to show overloads (not all shown):

```
function concat(arr1: [], arr2: []): [];
function concat<A>(arr1: [A], arr2: []): [A];
function concat<A, B>(arr1: [A, B], arr2: []): [A, B];
function concat<A, B, C>(arr1: [A, B, C], arr2: []): [A, B, C];
.......
```

My question is: why in the  **older versions of the language** we would need to use so many overloads? Are there no better primitives in the older versions of the language to type that function?

*Basically I want an answer which explains why none of the existing primitives in the older version of the language could be used to type this*

For example why not use `concat(arr1: any[], arr2: any[])`? etc.

Or why not use just tuples? Why we needed variadic?

Comment: "*Are there no better primitives in the older versions of the language to type that function?*" erm...no. That's what the docs are saying. There *wasn't* an alternative. Hence the variadic tuple types which tackle this.

Comment: @VLAZ That is not the question, my question is I wanted to hear explanation why none of the existing primitives in the old version could be used to solve that problem

Comment: _"none of the existing primitives "_ – Such as?

Comment: Because there wasn't any that could solve this? I really don't know what kind of explanation would help. You want proof of something not existing in the language? Where *the official documentation* speaks about the absence of and *a new feature was introduced* to cover the gap? I am afraid I cannot be more convincing that TS itself to the lack of support for variadic tuple alternatives in the past.

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine I don't know I am asking, I am learning the language, hence the question. I don't know, for example why not use `any[]`?

Comment: *"Basically I want an answer which explain why none of the existing primitives in the older version of the language would fit."* That's **far** too broad a question for SO's Q&A format. "Index types can't because ___. Mapped types can't because ___. Conditional types can't because ___." etc. etc. etc. If you have some specific feature you think would solve the problem other than function overloads, outlining your logic and asking where you've gone wrong *might* be on topic here, but frankly I don't think the TypeScript team just ... overlooked something.

Comment: `any[]` is not a tuple at all?

Comment: @VLAZ You don't understand the question. Question is why existing primitives could not fit, like why not type both arrays using `any[]`?

Comment: Because `any[]` has less information than a tuple

Comment: Yes, I don't understand how `any[]` its at all with the typing here.

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine I meant `concat(arr1: any[], arr2: any[])`

Comment: @VLAZ I meant `concat(arr1: any[], arr2: any[])`

Comment: The result of `concat([1, 2], [3])` is `[1, 2, 3]` *at type level*. It is not `[true, "banana", {hello: "world"}]` nor `[]` nor `[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]` nor anything else. `any[]` elides that information entirely.

Comment: @John In the example in the docs you see different return types for different function signatures. That's a lot of information. If you use `any[]`, you only get `any[]` as a return type. That's a little information. A lot is more than a little.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't understand  your comment.

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine Ah you see now that is different answer. It seems you are getting to the bottom of the question unlike others here :) So yeah I was looking for explanation why I could not use existing alternatives, why would they fail

Comment: When you concat two tuples, you still get a tuple back. It will have 1. the combined elements of the two tuples. With the correct positions, and types. `any[]` gives you *no* information about the length, *no* information about types, *no* information about which position holds what.

Comment: @VLAZ Anyway I hope now my question is finally clear. If anyone can write an answer understandable for a beginner that's fine.

Comment: @John You're seeing something that isn't there :) I honestly thought that you know a TS feature that I don't, and I was curious to learn about it.

Comment: @John, I understand your frustration. Believe me, we don't try to hurt your feelings, don't get defensive. Both VLAZ and T.J. Crowder are well-known StackOverflow experts, the only thing that they do is help solve problems.

Answer (score 3):

The primary goal of TypeScript is to add type information to otherwise untyped bare JavaScript. There are constructs like `any` that don't have type information, but they have specific purpose to be a temporary placeholder for transitioning from bare JavaScript to TypeScript.

When using TypeScript and writing a custom `concat(…)` function, one might want to reflect the fact that `concat([T, U], [V, W])` is not just *some array*, but precisely `[T, U, V, W]`.

*("T", "U", "V", and "W" here are common placeholders for types.)*

Now imagine that this function can accept any two arrays of any type. In order to write typings for such a function using pre-4.0 TypeScript you would have to use function overloads. This quickly gets *very* repetitive:

- *"if the first array is `[]` and the second array is `[]`, the result is `[]`"*
- *"if the first array is `[T]`, and the second array is `[]`, the result is `[T]`"*
- *"if the first array is `[T, U]`, and the second array is `[]`, the result is `[T, U]`"*
- *"if the first array is `[]`, and the second array is `[V]`, the result is `[V]`"*
- *"if the first array is `[T]`, and the second array is `[V]`, the result is `[T, V]`"*
- …

… and so on. That's very painful, isn't it?

With TypeScript 4.0+ you can just *infer* the types of the input arrays and combine them *ahead of time*:

- *"the first array is some tuple `A`, and the second array is some tuple `B`, and the result is `[...A, ...B]`"*

All the necessary information is there, there's nothing left to add. Hence, you don't need to use the repetitive and verbose overloads.

Answer (score 0):

it is mentioned right after:

"TypeScript 4.0 brings two fundamental changes, along with inference improvements, to make typing these possible."

Inference is the key word here. In other words typescript became smarter in understanding the code and figuring out which possible types could result out of [...arr, ...arr2]

In older versions you would need to do the "hard" work, now typescript is doing it for you.

Comment: why they needed variadic tuples? why could not we have used just tuples?

Comment: @john *how* would you use "just tuples"? Other than overloads.